# How can i color the codes

Tags: html

I have a new library that I will publish soon on Github but I need create documentation tutorial on my library website the question is how I can put code in code space ?

check image below

[image]

and how can i color the codes, Is there easy way for that without a lot codes

Comment: So you want to have the looks of a script with a gray background right? It might be a little bit of a pain to re-code everything since you would need to exactly specify each tag with its own color via javascript.

Comment: @GrandIQ Yes, that's why I said I want a simple way because I think it will take a lot of time if I build it myself

Comment: @GrandIQ Do you think there is a library ready for codes colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use open source syntax highlighting libraries such as [highlightJS](https://highlightjs.org)

Answer (score 2):

How about PrismJS, allows you to select by passing a specific class name, such as css, javascript, html, etc...

https://prismjs.com/

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.16.0/themes/prism.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.16.0/prism.min.js"></script>

For Example (CSS):

<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , But I see highlightJS website is better

Comment: @polomy Your welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: Love you. Very good

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use, [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org). This provides a syntax highlighting using `js` and `css`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('pre code').forEach((block) => {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/highlight.min.js"></script>


<pre><code class="css">
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}
</code></pre>
```